# cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace '' does not exist"

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm trying to use [python driver for cassandra](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/installation.html)
but when I run these three lines in python shell

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('demo')
```

I get this error

```
cassandra.InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Keyspace 'demo' does not exist"
```

pip freeze says `cassandra-driver==2.5.0`

I checked cqlsh

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.4 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> describe keyspaces

system_traces  system

cqlsh>
```

there is no keyspace named 'demo' but I'm just following these two tutorials and they haven't said anything about pre creating keyspace
http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-cassandra-and-python/
http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions for creating the 'demo' keyspace are at a page linked from http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-cassandra-and-python/:

> To follow this tutorial, you should already have a running Cassandra instance, and have gone through the 10 minute walkthrough here: http://www.PlanetCassandra.org/try-cassandra/

The try-cassandra page has a link for the developer walkthrough (click on "Start Developer Walkthrough").  The developer walk through has a step for creating the 'demo' keyspace:

> The keyspace can include operational elements, such as replication factor and data center awareness. Let’s create a keyspace called “demo”. We will include replication strategy class and factor; details that will be covered in a future tutorial.
>
> To create the keyspace “demo”, at the CQL shell prompt, type:
>
> cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

To create the table

```
use demo;
CREATE TABLE users (
  firstname text,
  lastname text,
  age int,
  email text,
  city text,
PRIMARY KEY (lastname));
```

Comment: Good find, Andy.  I also thought that was odd that they didn't include the `CREATE KEYSPACE` statement.